# How can I tell if I am overtraining my support vector machine?

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm

I am trying to train a Support Vector Machine (SVM) classifier to classify various items into 5 categories. I have trained two SVM classifiers, however, I am concerned that the accuracies and F1 scores do not change when some parameters are changed.

**SVM Classifier 1 Parameters:**
c = 0.001, 
kernel = poly, 
degree = 5, 
coef0 = 2.5, 
tol = 0.001, 
gamma = auto

**SVM Classifier 1 Results:** 
Accuracy = 100%
F1Score Weighted = 100%

If I were to change some of the parameters such as...

**SVM Classifier 2 Parameters:**
c = 1.0 
kernel = poly, 
degree = 1, 
coef0 = 0.0, 
tol = 0.001, 
gamma = auto

**SVM Classifier 2 Results:** 
Accuracy = 100%
F1Score Weighted = 100%

Is it at all concerning that changing some of the parameters like C, degree, and coef0 do not change the overall results?

Comment: Does 100% accuracy make sense for any parameterization? It seems like you may just have a Very Easy problem that can be solved perfectly over a wide range of parameters. If you don't think the problem should be so easy to solve, you may have an issue in how you're computing performance metrics.

Comment: I do not believe the problem should solved this easily as the dataset I am working with is quite inter-twined and shows no good linear (or polynomial) separation. This is the reason I am concerned that a value of 100% accuracy is the result I am getting. What other items do you think I should look into or consider here?

Comment: How would you detect overfitting in any supervised learning problem?

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica Depending on the SL algorithm, I would change the number of component of levels and see where the accuracy peaks, with the maximum being the best value to use. However, I have found that with SVMs this is not always the case.

Comment: What is a component level and how it that relate to model selection?